# I want to convert all number between tag with regex in a file txt

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to modify numbers to two decimals.
For each number between the `<td>` tags, I want to modify so it includes two decimals.

**Input**

```
<TD>25.5</TD> 
<TD>45.6</TD> 
<TD>19</TD> 
<TD>25</TD>
```

**Desired output**

```
<TD>25.50</TD> 
<TD>45.60</TD> 
<TD>19.00</TD> 
<TD>25.00</TD>
```

Code:

```
        string text = File.ReadAllText("pop.txt");
        try
        {
            string pattern = @"(<TD>(.+?)</TD>)";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
            var result = (from Match m in matches select (m.Groups[2].ToString())).ToList<string>();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                var a = Convert.ToDouble(item).ToString("#,##.00");
                string s = String.Format("{0:0.##}", item); 
                text = text.Replace(item,a);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

Comment: I didn't put this on hold, but you need to be more clear. There's not even a properly formed question in there. For instance, is the output what you are getting now, or expected behavior?

Comment: I want to convert all number between <TD></TD> to double

exemple:

<TD>25.5</TD> 

<TD>45.6</TD> 

<TD>19</TD> 

<TD>25</TD>

to

<TD>25.50</TD> 

<TD>45.60</TD> 

<TD>19.00</TD> 
<TD>25.00</TD>

Comment: Don't clarify in a comment, update your post. ;)

Comment: Where are you stuck or what results differing the from the desired output are you getting? This is not a free debugging or write-code-for-me service

Comment: ok My code gives the following result                                                                               <TD>25,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00</TD>

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

```
var input = "<TD>25.5</TD><TD>45.6</TD><TD>19</TD><TD>25</TD><TD>.03</TD>";

var regex = new Regex(@"<TD>(\d*?)\.?(\d?\d?).*?</TD>");

var output = regex.Replace(input, match => {
    var rigth = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var left = match.Groups[2].Value.PadRight(2, '0');
    return $"<TD>{(rigth.Length == 0 ? "0" : rigth)}.{left}</TD>";
});
```

### Explanation

`<TD>` find <TD>
`(\d*?)` find 0 or more digits and capture them (?not greedy)
`\.?` optional dot
`(\d?\d?)` 2 optional digits captured
`.*?` rest untill `</TD>`